# Delimiters in the wrong places

Tags: r, csv, data-cleaning

I'm importing a TSV file into R but some of the tabs are in the wrong spot. For example, I want:

```
Name        Appointment
John Doe    12:30
Jane Doe    1:00
Rick Smith  11:45
Susy Smith  10:15
```

But instead I'm getting

```
Name        Appointment
John Doe    12:30
Jane        Doe 1:00
Rick Smith  11:45
Susy        Smith  10:15
```

There's no real pattern as it's user error. I've developed a work around with substr() to extract the appointment time, but then I lose the last name.

I also tried

```
separate(Data, col = Appointment, c("last", "time"), " ")
```

and working from there but this doesn't work either as the number of spaces between the last name and the time is variable, and the formatting is inconsistent:

```
Name        Last    Time
John Doe    12:30
Jane        Doe     1:00
Rick Smith  11:45
Susy        Smith
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question!

Comment: You absolutely should change your export such that you either have a proper delimiter separating the logical fields, or else put quotes around single terms which may have whitespace in them.  This isn't an R problem from my point of view, your source data is the culprit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can read this with `readLines`, change the delimiter and then use `read.csv`

```
df1 <- read.csv(text=sub("([a-z])\\s+([0-9])", "\\1, \\2", lines[-1]),
 header = FALSE, col.names = strsplit(lines[1], "\\s+")[[1]], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

To remove the extra spaces in 'Name', use the `gsub`

```
df1$Name <- gsub("\\s+", " ", df1$Name)
```

giving us the output

```
df1
#        Name Appointment
#1   John Doe       12:30
#2   Jane Doe        1:00
#3 Rick Smith       11:45
#4 Susy Smith       10:15
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines("file.txt")
```

Comment: I'm not too hot with regular expression so just to make sure I'm understanding,
    sub("([a-z])\\s+([0-9])", "\\1, \\2", lines[-1])

is saying "find observations that are a string and one or more spaces followed by numbers, then replace them with that same string followed by a comma followed by the numeric." 

Sorry this is a bit over my head but also incredibly helpful

Comment: @Oct Exactly. By using the `(..)`, we capture it as a group, then use the backreference (`\\1`) to get the captured group in the replacement

Comment: I seem to be having trouble applying the replacement argument to my data. For example I have

    J,R 

in the name column so I tried 

    read.csv(text=sub(pattern = "[A-Z][:punct:][A-Z]", "\\1\\3", lines[-1])

and 

    read.csv(text=sub(pattern = "[A-Z],[A-Z]", "\\1\\3", lines[-1])

The former doesn't do any replacement, the latter just deletes the pattern from the data and doesn't replace it with anything.

Comment: @Oct My pattern was based on the example you provided

Comment: Correct, there are several different errors with the delimiters though so I'm trying to apply your pattern to various scenarios. After changing the delimiters to commas J\\tR became J,R and I'm trying to replace it with JR,

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. Just dropped some parenthesis so that's why the back references weren't working. Thanks a ton for your help, you're a life saver.